# Ubercart - Chosen Delivery Date to limit Shipping Options?

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, ubercart

On the check out page I need users to choose a delivery date. Their needs to be multiple shipping options (that cost different amounts), but these are restricted based on what day you choose. Alternately if you choose a shipping method first, this will restrict what days you can choose for delivery.

One shipping option is ‘saturday’, and the delivery date must be a saturday.

Another shipping option is ‘next day’, the delivery must be the next day, and the order must be made before 2pm.

The final option is 'standard', which has no limitations except it cant be delivered on a saturday,  and the delivery cant be the next day.

Also, I need to be able to restrict dates for delivery for all shipping options, as deliveries wont be made on bank holidays or the day after.

Im really struggling to do this so Id appreciate any pointers. If I can only achieve some of what I need that may be ok as a compromise.

Thanks

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/uc_deliverytimeslot or 
http://drupal.org/project/uc_ddate
If any of these modules doesn't satisfy you then i think you need to develop a custom module. and a personal advice - try to upgrade to commerce module(but available from drupal 7 only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect case for using a calendar table to identify which dates are actually holidays.  While I don't have specific experience with Ubercart, I've used calendar tables in a number of different solutions, and even wrote up a blog entry that details how to create and use a calendar table with a MySQL server. It's quite long, so rather than post the whole thing here, I'll just point you to the actual entry at http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables.